# How to move my ext4 partition ahead of my boot partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount

[image]

I have a 10.04 GB partition (`/dev/sda6`) just above my boot partition. I want to merge it with the `/dev/sda8`, which is 73 GB. How do I move this partition? I tried to unmount but to no avail. I don't want to loose the data on the 73 GB partition.

Comment: You can't merge partitions. You can delete it and use it's space to expand some other partition.

Comment: So you mean to say I delete boot, I merge both the partition, resplit and boot into the upper partion? and merge the below and 73 GB one

Comment: I mean you delete sda6, then move sda7.

Comment: You are showing extended partition mounted, you must unmount it, by using swapoff or unmounting the swap partition. Live installer likes to mount swap. If reinstalling, usually better not to have a separate /boot partition for standard desktop installs. May be required for server or LVM configurations.

Comment: There is no such thing as "merge". You can create/delete/resize/move partitions. Doing what you're asking doesn't gain you much. Your disk is full. However, you've got a 30GiB unallocated space in front of sda4 that could be used to accomplish what you want, and along with the sda6 partition, would give you enough to resize sda8 and make it worth while. The procedure is somewhat complicated, and not for the faint of heart. What is currently on sda6? Let me know if you need specific steps.

Comment: Note that there is a very good historical reason for /boot being a separate partition and placed where it is.  The short version is that it makes old computer boot reliably on big harddisks.   I would suggest that you make a backup of your system (which you should anyway as you do not want to loose data on the 73GB partition), and reinstall using a single partition using the whole disk.  Then you can restore from your backup.  Less fun, but more robust plus you get a backup of your data.

Comment: @heynnema Sda6 is currently empty. It has 10 GB space which I wanted to give to my /home partition. Looks like that is going to one hell of a job.

Comment: @oldfred Anyway could I move that 30GB /dev/sda4 below /dev/sda5? I want to give more space to ubuntu /home directory but really limited by the fact the /boot is in front of it and stops any space that could be used to merge /home and free space from /dev/sda5

Comment: @oldfred is possible to have /home or /dev/sda8 before /boot or /dev/sda7, so that /home always has room to expand upwards, by whatever free space /dev/sda5 provides(considering /sda6 is subsumed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your looking at a tricky and dangerous process.  ***I warn you beforehand:  BACKUP YOUR DATA!!!***

So here are the steps, if I understand what you want correctly.

#### 1. Backup your data.

Backup the data on your entire hard drive to another drive.  If possible, backup the data *and* make a disk image, so that you can write back to your main drive if something goes wrong.

**2. Boot up a live CD**

Distro to your choice; I would go for Ubuntu 16.04 personally, but it's your choice.

**3. Open GParted**

I prefer to start it with sudo privs right away, so go to the terminal and type:

```
 sudo gparted
```

**4. Delete partition `/dev/sda6`.**

This will erase any data on it, which is *one of the many reasons* you should back up your data before even beginning this process - see step 1.

**5. Move partition `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda8` up on the free space.**

Incidentally, this is why you have to do this in live CD: you have to move your root partition, which you cannot do while the partition is live.  To do this, you'll have to go to the `Partition` menu. Use the `Resize/Move` option from the menu to *move* `/dev/sda7` over as far to left as it will go and to *grow* `/dev/sda8` over to the left as far as it will go.

**6. Expand partition `/dev/sda8` to include the free unallocated space at the end.**

This will grow your 73 GB partition around 83 GB, which is the sum of the size of your two partitions.

**7. Copy the data out of your backup of `/dev/sda6` onto the `/dev/sda8` partition.**

... and you're done, provided you didn't hit any glitches.  :)

**8. After that install && boot-repair**
as you would have broken the grub(due to boot moving from sda7 to sda6), Installing and running boot-repair should fix it.

**DISCLAIMER: Backup your data before running this process.  Whenever you start playing with partitions on your hard drive, you have a risk of losing data.**

Comment: "Tricky and dangerous", "high risk of losing data". Well said - very true!

Comment: /dev/sda6 is completely empty. But I did not understand when you said move partition /dev/sda7 and /dev/sda8. Let me get back to you on this tomorrow with the exact screen shot. I will give full night for my backup and start the process tomorrow morning.

Comment: @SarasArya, I've edited to improve clarity.

Comment: Yay... It worked!!! That was one clear answer @anonymous2

Comment: @SarasArya, great to hear!  Always great when it works nicely like that.